# How to print each variable vertically in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vertical-alignment

This is my entire code:

```
days=["Sunday: ", "Monday: ", "Tuesday: ", "Wednesday: ", "Thursday: ", "Friday: ", "Saturday: "]
demand=[]
temp=[]
demand=[15, 20, 25, 18, 20, 22, 14]
while demand[0]>0 or demand[1]>0 or demand[2]>0 or demand[3]>0 or demand[4]>0 or demand[5]>0 or demand[6]>0:
    min1=min(demand)
    ind1=demand.index(min1)
    temp=demand.copy()
    temp[ind1]=100000
    min2=min(temp)
    ind2=temp.index(min2)
    print(min1, ind1, min2, ind2)
    for i in range(7):
        if i != ind1 and i != ind2:
            demand[i]-=1
    print(demand)
print(days[0], demand[0]+15, days[1], demand[1]+20, days[2], demand[2]+25, days[3], demand[3]+18, days[4], demand[4]+20, days[5], demand[5]+22, days[6], demand[6]-14)
```

I want to print the last `print` command vertically so it turns out in the end like so:

```
Sunday:     15
Monday:     20
Tuesday:    25
Wednesday:  18
Thursday:   20
Friday:     22
Saturday:   14
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to have separate `print` statements for each line in a `for` loop:

```
offsets = [15, 20, 25, 18, 20, 22, -14]
for day in range(7):
    print(days[day], demand[day] + offsets[day])
```

Comment: It's not enough effort to warrant posting a competing answer, but `print(f'{days[day]:11}{demand[day] + offsets[day]:3}')`, for example, would give neat columns per the OP's request.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-44-2628afb4612c>", line 21, in <module>
    print(days[day], demand[day]+offsets[day])

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `'int' object is not subscriptable` means you've written something like `foo[bar]` but when it actually runs, `foo` is an integer number not a list (or a dict or something else that can be addressed in that way). As @Selcuk suggests, the most likely cause is a typo where you're trying to index into the wrong variable, or you have overwritten the variable that contained the list with a value that's just a number.